# Best modern C++ way to handle a std::array of shared_ptrs?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

In my class `Box` I have a member variable  `std::array<Object*, N> m_objects`. In a member function in `Box`, I set the `Object`s in the `std::array` via 
`this->m_objects[i] = make_shared<Object>("<some parameters>");`.

Is this the best modern C++ 11 (or newer) approach?

Comment: I doubt you successfully assigned a `std::shared_ptr<Object>` to a `Object*`.

Comment: Why `this->`? Omit it if not required, which should definitely the case if members are prefixed with `m_`.

Comment: I'm still quite new to C++, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann this is a nitpick. There are much more important issues in his code, as Quentin pointed out. Did that compile? I don't think so.

Comment: @UmNyobe This is a question of style regardless of the issue at hand. I was just pointing that out to OP.

Comment: accidentally I missed the error in the console with the error message. I guess it should bestd::array<std::shared_ptr<Object>, N> m_objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this->m_objects[i]` takes a raw pointer to Object (`Object*`).
An array of shared_ptr would be `std::array<std::shared_ptr<Object>,N>`.

I would consider instead:

1. If you know you want N elements, why do you allocate dynamically? why not an std::array by value (`std::array<Object,N>`)
2. If you don't necessarily want N objects, why use an std::array and not an std::vector?
3. Do you really need shared ownership on these pointers? If you don't, it's more efficient to use an std::unique_ptr

Comment: To 1: I allocate dynamically since I have to determine some parameters for the ctor beforehand. 2: I have a fixed number N, so array should fit here. 3: Yes, I can't have it to be unique.

Comment: If you allocate an array of std::unique_ptr, you can still share the objects by giving out raw pointers to it (with .get() method), but all the Objects would be destructed when Box is destructed. 
If instead you use shared_ptr, and you share the shared_ptr with others, the Object will only be destructed when all shared_ptrs are destructed (or stop pointing to it)

Comment: I tried to switch to std::unique_ptr, but then I get in each class an "error: use of deleted function"

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to copy a unique_ptr? that is not possible. you can move a unique_ptr (by using std::move)